# keyboard not opening in react native otp input

Tags: react-native

I'm beginner in react native and trying to design a OTP input boxes. On opening screen keyboard is not opening. First placeholder is autofocused but keyboard is not opening. I'm using this library.

[React native otp input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@twotalltotems/react-native-otp-input)

Comment: is this on the device or the simulator?

Comment: I was facing this on device

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71636139/15368274 above answer works fine if not try to give ref

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `autoFocusOnLoad={false}` it's working on my side.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

```
const OTPContainer = () => {
const otpRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
setTimeout(() => otpRef.current.focusField(0), 250);
}, []);

return <OTPInputView ref={otpRef} autoFocusOnLoad={false}/>}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set

> autoFocusOnLoad = {true}

It will do your work as well as it would fix your issue also.
:)